# Parity and Time reversal when the number of space or time dimensions is even

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, spacetime, parity, time-reversal-symmetry

There's a side remark in the middle of section 2.6 of *Weinberg I* that I find a bit unclear.

Suppose that $L(p)$ is a boost that carries the four momentum $k^\mu=(0,0,0,M)$ to $p^\mu$, and that ${\bf T}$ and ${\bf P}$ are the time reversal and parity operators respectively. Then:

$$ {\bf T} L(p) {\bf T}^{-1} = L ({\bf P}p)$$

with:
$$ {\bf P}p = (-\vec p, \sqrt{p^2+M^2})$$

This is fine for me. But then Weinberg says:

> That is, changing the sign of each element of $L^\mu_\nu$ with an odd number
>   of time indices is the same as changing the signs of elements with an odd
>   number of space-indices.

Now, considering that ${\bf T}=-{\bf P}$ independently of the number of dimensions, the equations above should continue to apply even in, say, a (2, 1) universe. What is the real meaning of the remark above?

Comment: I don't think this comment says anything deep. There are only one of three different index structures for $L^\mu_\nu$. It can have (1) two time indices, (2) two space indices or (3) one time index and one space-index. That sentence is simply saying that you change the sign of all components with index structure (3) keeping all else the same. This statement is of course independent of dimension. This is how I interpret it. More generally, you can ask how ${\bf T}$ acts on more general tensors with many indices.

Comment: Oh,  I see.  Thanks a lot. It did not occur to me that he was talking about the number of indices rather than their range. I would upvote your comment or accept it as an answer if I could.